# R: sha1 hashing - different results than online

Tags: r, hash, sha1

I have to exchange large files with two colleagues. One of them works in `R` another in a different environment (not sure exactly which one). I hash long strings in it using `digest` with standard `sha1` to save space, e.g.

```
library(digest)
sapply("2016_Silverado_1500__CW_LS__Standard_Fragile_Static_US_ENG_v1_160x600.jpg", digest, "sha1")
2016_Silverado_1500__CW_LS__Standard_Fragile_Static_US_ENG_v1_160x600.jpg 
                               "e18f03a6e0949d6149aba07bd8295e7249f3b38d"
```

Colleagues then hash their strings and search for same hash in my file. Is it guaranteed that our hashes will be the same? I'm worried now because online generator produced different hash:

http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator

hex: be5c711f15f874ecdcb5b99e655264afa53170c5

Comment: a. `sapply` is not doing anything here. b. It's hashing the name, not the file. To do that, you'll need to pass it an R object. Reading the file in with something like `jpeg::readJPEG` may work, but I'm not an expert on how images are stored.

Comment: I know it's hashing the name. I am not passing a real image there

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@AlexeyFerapontov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4339116/alexey-ferapontov)'s question post.

> ```
> digest("2016_Silverado_1500__CW_LS__Standard_Fragile_Static_US_ENG_v1_160x600.jpg", algo="sha1", serialize=F)
> [1] "be5c711f15f874ecdcb5b99e655264afa53170c5"
> ```